# Syntax error with variable

Tags: java

I am having errors below and I am confused why this is a Lab to make a storage spot for a students information.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

I have a problem with the square brackets below

```
public class Student {
    private String studentID;
    private String studentName;
    private String studentMajor;
    private double studentGPA;
    private String studentGrad;
    private long[] ;
```

And a problem with Student() below

```
    public Student(){
        studentID = "";
        studentName = "";
        studentMajor = "";
        studentGPA = 0;
        studentGrad = "";
    }   

    public Student(String stuID, String stuName, String stuMajor, double stuGPA, String stuGrad) {
        studentID = stuID;
        studentName = stuName;
        studentMajor = stuMajor;
        studentGPA = stuGPA;
        studentGrad = stuGrad;
    }

    public void setID(String ID) {
        studentID = ID;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        studentName = name;
    }

    public void setMajor(String major) {
        studentMajor = major;
    }

    public void setGPA(double GPA) {
        studentGPA = GPA;
    }

    public void setGrad(String Grad) {
        studentGrad = Grad;
    }

    public String getID() {
        return studentID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public String getMajor() {
        return studentMajor;
    }

    public double getGPA() {
        return studentGPA;
    }

    public String getGrad() {
        return studentGrad;
    }

    public void printData() {
        System.out.println("Student ID: "+studentID);
        System.out.println("Student Name: " +studentName );
        System.out.println("Student Major: "+studentMajor); 
        System.out.println("Student GPA: "+ studentGPA); 
        System.out.println("Student Year of Graduation: " +studentGrad);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the error messages you're getting.

Answer (score 2):

`private long[];` is incorrect syntax.

To complete the variable you must insert an identifier (the variable name).

In most IDE's (i.e. Eclipse and Netbeans), this incomplete variable will cause the next line to have issues. This is why `public Student(){` (despite being completely valid code) is giving you an error. If you temporarily delete the line `private long[];` you should see this error go away.

From the code you supplied, it looks like `private long[];` can be deleted anyway as an array isn't being used.